# Tracking AWS KMS activities

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

Is there a way to track or log what AWS KMS is using which key for which purposes.

I noticed that in some accounts that we do not use KMS, there are still KMS activities in the billing. In fact, there are activities in every region.

While these activities are in the free tier, it would be transparent to know what are these activities. Especially so since "keys" are involved.

Answer (score 3):

You can log all KMS activites with CloudTrail.

[Logging AWS KMS API Calls Using AWS CloudTrail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html)